# Are there any merits which delay the adulterer's explosion?

Tags: death, arayot, sotah-secluded-woman, tractate-sotah

In mSotah 5:1 it states that the Sotah waters check the woman and her presumed consort. I assume this 'checking' leads to the consort suffering the same death as the woman. The [talmud](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.21a.12) further states that certain merits stave off the woman's demise for a period of time (according to some opinions). I would like to know if the consort is able to stave off his own death with merits as well.